# Any Tezos RPC alternatives suggestions

Tags: smart-contracts, rpc, testing

The open tezos docs suggest using RPC URL: "https://florencenet.smartpy.io/". It does not work.

What alternatives RPC URLs do you use. It seems that when you use the mainnet RPC URL - things tend to work. Any others for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://smartpy.io/nodes

`florencenet` is a dead testing network, that's why it doesn't work. You need to use a current testing network RPC. The current testing network mimicking mainnet is `hangzhounet`.

If you want to test the next protocol, use `ithacanet` RPC.

Answer (score 0):

This RPC node also works well
https://hangzhounet.api.tez.ie/

Comment: That's the one I go for now